# How do I Successfully Echo a For Loop Into a Batch Script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
echo for /f "delims=" %%%i in ^(^'DIR /A -H /B^'^) do set "check^=^^!check^^!,"%%%i"" >> Uninstall.cmd
```

Results in

```
for /f "delims=" %%i""
```

Original Code I'm trying to echo into Uninstall.cmd

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('DIR /A -H /B') do set "check=!check!,"%%i""
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to get that line of code to be escaped fully so that it can be outputted to a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have delayed expansion enabled

```
echo for /f "delims=" %%%%i in ('DIR /A-H /B') do set "check=!check!,"%%%%i""
```

If you have delayed expansion enabled, the exclamation points needs to be escaped

```
echo for /f "delims=" %%%%i in ('DIR /A-H /B') do set "check=^!check^!,"%%%%i""
```

BUT, if the code is executed inside a block, the closing parenthesis needs also to be escaped

```
if 1==1 (
    echo for /f "delims=" %%%%i in ('DIR /A-H /B'^) do set "check=!check!,"%%%%i""

    :: OR

    echo for /f "delims=" %%%%i in ('DIR /A-H /B'^) do set "check=^!check^!,"%%%%i""
)
```